# html2pdf zip multiple pdf files php mysql

Tags: php, pdf, zip

I need to zip multiple pdf documents generated with html2pdf. I managed to create the pdf files in the tmp/ directory but the zip file created cannot be opened. Any idea ?

This is what I did:

```
<?php
$tmp='/opt/lampp/htdocs/rapport/tmp';
$file = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/rapport/tmp/my-pdf.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

ob_start();
```

Here the part to save the zip file with all the pdf files inside:

```
try
    {
        
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        //$content=ob_end_clean();
        //$html2pdf->Output($tablename.'-'.$idEcht.'-NGSReport.pdf','F');
        //$html2pdf->Output(__DIR__ .$tablename.'-'.$idEcht.'-NGSReport.pdf','F');
        $html2pdf->Output('/opt/lampp/htdocs/rapport/tmp/'.$tablename.'-'.$idEcht.'-NGSReport.pdf','F');
        // ADD PDF FILE TO ZIP
                      
        $zip->addFile('/opt/lampp/htdocs/rapport/tmp/'.$tablename.'-'.$idEcht.'-NGSReport.pdf');
        
        unset($html2pdf);
        
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }

   
}
}
//After I loop ends, I close the zip file and force download
$zip->close();
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-pdf.zip"');
readfile('my-pdf.zip');
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Open the ZIP file in a program like vim or notepad. If the first two bytes aren't `PK` then you have extra stuff at the beginning of the file which you'll need to fix. Next, look at the very end of the file for any PHP/HTML output.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I opened the zip file with nano, I have html code inside the zip, especially this interesting line: `<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(my-pdf.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Since you are creating the file using an absolute path, you should probably read from it the same

Comment: @ChrisHaas, you are right, I changed the path in readline: `readfile('/opt/lampp/htdocs/rapport/tmp/my-pdf.zip');`. What I don't understand, the zip does not open when I download it: `an error occured` but it is readable from `opt/lampp/htdocs/rapport/tmp/`

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I have HTML output inside the zip archive which I don't have into the tmp folder. How do we remove this HTML output. Do you why I have this HTML output inside my zip archive when I download it from the browser?

Comment: You don't have it in the archive, you have it in the HTTP stream. The moment after you transmit a file to the client you should call `exit` as the next statement.

Comment: I put `exit;` directly after `header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-pdf.zip"');
readfile('/opt/lampp/htdocs/rapport/tmp/my-pdf.zip');
mysqli_close($conn);
exit;` but still the same error

Comment: Once again, open the zip file, if you see HTML it is probably a PHP error that needs to be corrected.

Comment: I have HTML at the begining of the ZIP file, not at the end anymore with the exit. the html are the headers and the body

Comment: Move your PHP logic for generating a ZIP file and sending it to the client to a dedicated file that doesn't have any header or body. You can send a ZIP file to the client, or HTML, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to figure out why I still have corrupted ZIP archive even if I removed HTML header and body...